# How to get the selected radio button’s value?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, radio-button

I’m having some strange problem with my JS program. I had this working properly but for some reason it’s no longer working. I just want to find the value of the radio button (which one is selected) and return it to a variable. For some reason it keeps returning `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
function findSelection(field) {
    var test = 'document.theForm.' + field;
    var sizes = test;

    alert(sizes);
        for (i=0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            if (sizes[i].checked==true) {
            alert(sizes[i].value + ' you got a value');     
            return sizes[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

`submitForm`:

```
function submitForm() {

    var genderS =  findSelection("genderS");
    alert(genderS);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#n" name="theForm">

    <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="genderS" value="1" checked> Male
    <input type="radio" name="genderS" value="0" > Female<br><br>
    <a href="javascript: submitForm()">Search</A>
</form>
```

Comment: @Machavity: this isn't the duplicate. The other question is the duplicate.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) {
    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
    alert(radios[i].value);

    // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="gender">Gender: </label>
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="1" checked="checked">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="0">Female</input>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxxd3/610/)

Edit: Thanks HATCHA and jpsetung for your edit suggestions.

Comment: That was working for jquery 1.7 but now the correct syntax for jQuery 1.9 is $('input[name="genderS"]:checked').val();   (remove the @)

Comment: I believe the `@` syntax was [deprecated even earlier](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) than that (jquery 1.2)

Comment: @TomPietrosanti the documentation appears to be a little off, http://jsfiddle.net/Xxxd3/608/ works in <1.7.2 but not in >1.8.3. Regardless, the `@` should definitely be removed

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they left some backwards compatibility in there, but didn't update the docs to match.  I remember some hoopla when they dropped some deprecated features that were still widely in use, so they added support back in.  Maybe that's why...

Comment: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) should probably be the recommended approach in straight JavaScript now.

Comment: for...of is supported by all modern browsers, and is a little easer to read / understand. so `for (let radio of radios) { \\do stuff }`

Comment: `const checkedRadio = radios.find(({ checked }) => checked);` will get the first (and only, in this case) input with truthy `checked`. If there is a chance that none is checked, you'll want to make sure that `checkedRadio` is not null.

Answer (score 575):

This works with any explorer.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="genderS"]:checked').value;
```

This is a simple way to get the value of any input type.
You also do *not* need to include jQuery path.

Comment: Using document.querySelector() is a pure javascript answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Comment: If you store it in a variabel and no radiobutton is selected you cause the browser to stop. Console says: TypeError `document.querySelector(...)` is `null`.

Comment: That does only work if one is selected. So you should check it before.

`var selector = document.querySelector('input[name="genderS"]:checked');
if(selector) console.log(selector.value);`

Comment: I'm working with Templates in Meteor,and that `:checked` trick totally nailed it for me.. for me the fix to reading radio buttons from a Meteor Template form was `accountType = template.find("[name='optradio']:checked").value;`

Comment: And you can use it in jQuery by using:`$('input[name="genderS"]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 64):

```
document.forms.your-form-name.elements.radio-button-name.value
```

Comment: This works too: `document.forms.your-form-name.name-shared-by-radio-buttons.value`

Comment: I think most people are overlooking this.  The accepted answer works.  Giorgos Tsakonas answer is better.  But this one is the fundamentally correct answer.  This one is how radio buttons actually work.  Note that if nothing has been selected, it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 33):

Since jQuery 1.8, the correct syntax for the query is

```
$('input[name="genderS"]:checked').val();
```

Not `$('input[@name="genderS"]:checked').val();` anymore, which was working in jQuery 1.7 (with the **@**).

Answer (score 24):

## ECMAScript 6 version

```
let genderS = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("genderS")).find(r => r.checked).value;
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a nice way to get the checked radio button's value with plain JavaScript:

```
const form = document.forms.demo;
const checked = form.querySelector('input[name=characters]:checked');

// log out the value from the :checked radio
console.log(checked.value);
```

Source: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/get-value-checked-radio-buttons

Using this HTML:

```
<form name="demo">
  <label>
    Mario
    <input type="radio" value="mario" name="characters" checked>
  </label>
  <label>
    Luigi
    <input type="radio" value="luigi" name="characters">
  </label>
  <label>
    Toad
    <input type="radio" value="toad" name="characters">
  </label>
</form>
```

You could also use [Array Find](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/array-find-javascript) the `checked` property to find the checked item:

```
Array.from(form.elements.characters).find(radio => radio.checked);
```

Answer (score 10):

In case someone was looking for an answer and landed here like me, from Chrome 34 and Firefox 33 you can do the following:

```
var form = document.theForm;
var radios = form.elements['genderS'];
alert(radios.value);
```

or simpler:

```
alert(document.theForm.genderS.value);
```

refrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList/value

Comment: I really guess this is the preferred way to go today. One might however also select the form via `querySelector`, which works fine too: `const form = document.querySelector('form[name="somename"]')`.

Also one can set the value of `radios` with `radios.value = {value}`

However, selecting the radios directly (e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="some_radio"]')`) will *not* work, because it returns `NodeList` instead of `RadioNodeList`. This is why you have to select the form first.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: 
As said by Chips_100 you should use :

```
var sizes = document.theForm[field];
```

directly without using the test variable.

---

Old answer:

Shouldn't you `eval` like this ?

```
var sizes = eval(test);
```

I don't know how that works, but to me you're only copying a string.

Comment: eval is not the best option here... you might want to say `var sizes = document.theForm[field];` and delete the first assignment, so not using `test` variable anymore.

Comment: For my knowledge, would eval work as is? Or would it work only with `eval('var sizes=document.theForm.' + field)` ?

Comment: the eval statement in your answer `var sizes = eval(test);` would work that way (i just testet it in firebug).

Comment: That makes more sense, but I'm getting an error "Unexpected token [" on that line where I put `field` in brackets. Any guesses as to why?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
function findSelection(field) {
    var test = document.getElementsByName(field);
    var sizes = test.length;
    alert(sizes);
    for (i=0; i < sizes; i++) {
            if (test[i].checked==true) {
            alert(test[i].value + ' you got a value');     
            return test[i].value;
        }
    }
}


function submitForm() {

    var genderS =  findSelection("genderS");
    alert(genderS);
    return false;
}
```

A fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFgM/1/).

Answer (score 7):

This is pure JavaScript, based on the answer by @Fontas but with safety code to return an empty string (and avoid a `TypeError`) if there isn't a selected radio button:

```
var genderSRadio = document.querySelector("input[name=genderS]:checked");
var genderSValue = genderSRadio ? genderSRadio.value : "";
```

The code breaks down like this:

- Line 1: get a reference to the control that (a) is an `<input>` type, (b) has a `name` attribute of `genderS`, and (c) is checked.
- Line 2: If there is such a control, return its value. If there isn't, return an empty string. The `genderSRadio` variable is truthy if Line 1 finds the control and null/falsey if it doesn't.

For JQuery, use @jbabey's answer, and note that if there isn't a selected radio button it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 7):

First, shoutout to *ashraf aaref*, who's answer I would like to expand a little.

As MDN Web Docs suggest, using `RadioNodeList` is the preferred way to go:

```
// Get the form
const form = document.forms[0];

// Get the form's radio buttons
const radios = form.elements['color'];

// You can also easily get the selected value
console.log(radios.value);

// Set the "red" option as the value, i.e. select it
radios.value = 'red';
```

One might however also select the form via `querySelector`, which works fine too:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form[name="somename"]')
```

**However**, selecting the radios directly will **not** work, because it returns a simple `NodeList`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="color"]')
// Returns: NodeList [ input, input ]
```

While selecting the form first returns a `RadioNodeList`

```
document.forms[0].elements['color']
// document.forms[0].color # Shortcut variant
// document.forms[0].elements['complex[naming]'] # Note: shortcuts do not work well with complex field names, thus `elements` for a more programmatic aproach
// Returns: RadioNodeList { 0: input, 1: input, value: "red", length: 2 }
```

This is why you have to select the form first and then call the `elements` Method. Aside from all the `input` Nodes, the `RadioNodeList` also includes a property `value`, which enables this simple manipulation.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList/value

Comment: +1. Well explained. I was looking for an answer explaining the difference between using `elements` and using the shortcut variant. Thanks for that! Does the shortcut variant work on all major browsers?

Comment: What works for me is `document.querySelector('input[name=color]:checked')`, as someone said below
`

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is extremely old, but it can now be done in a single line

```js
function findSelection(name) {
    return document.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]:checked`).value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an Example for Radios where no *Checked="checked"* attribute is used

```
function test() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radiotest");
var found = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        alert(radios[i].value);
        found = 0;
        break;
    }
}
   if(found == 1)
   {
     alert("Please Select Radio");
   }    
}
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/hgdWp/2/ [**Click Find without selecting any Radio**]

Source (from my blog): http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2013/01/validateget-checked-radio-value-in.html

Answer (score 3):

Putting **Ed Gibbs**' answer into a general function:

```
function findSelection(rad_name) {
    const rad_val = document.querySelector('input[name=' + rad_name + ']:checked');
    return (rad_val ? rad_val.value : "");
}
```

Then you can do `findSelection("genderS");`

Answer (score 2):

lets suppose you need to place different rows of radio buttons in a form, each with separate attribute names ('option1','option2' etc) but the same class name. Perhaps you need them in multiple rows where they will each submit a value based on a scale of 1 to 5 pertaining to a question. you can write your javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName('ratings'); // we access all our radio buttons elements by class name     
    var radios="";

    var i;
    for(i=0;i<ratings.length;i++){
        ratings[i].onclick=function(){
            var result = 0;
            radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[class=ratings]:checked");
            for(j=0;j<radios.length;j++){
                result =  result + + radios[j].value;
            }
            console.log(result);
            document.getElementById('overall-average-rating').innerHTML = result; // this row displays your total rating
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would also insert the final output into a hidden form element to be submitted together with the form.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use brackets to get value from input, its way more clear than using dots.

```
document.forms['form_name']['input_name'].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a [formdata object](https://datacadamia.com/web/browser/formdata) as it represents the value that should be send if the form was submitted.

Note that it shows a snapshot of the form values. If you change the value, you need to recreate the FormData object. If you want to see the state change of the radio, you need to subscribe to the change event [change event demo](https://datacadamia.com/web/html/radio#event)

[Demo](https://datacadamia.com/web/html/radio):

```js
let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
console.log(`The value is: ${formData.get("choice")}`);
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Pizza crust:</p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="regular" >
        <label for="choice1id">Regular crust</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="deep" checked >
        <label for="choice2id">Deep dish</label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: this kind of works, but it doesn't update the value whenever you select "regular crust". it only shows the default value that it loads with

Comment: @greenie-beans It shows a snapshot of the form values. If you change the value, you need to recreate the `FormData` object. If you want to see the state change of the radio, you need to subscribe to the `change` event [change event demo](https://datacadamia.com/web/html/radio#event)

Comment: yeah. thanks for following up and sharing that. i think this answer is incomplete without that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to assign a Id for your form element(), this way can be considered as a safe alternative way (specially when radio group element name is not unique in document):

```
function findSelection(field) {
    var formInputElements = document.getElementById("yourFormId").getElementsByTagName("input");
    alert(formInputElements);
        for (i=0; i < formInputElements.length; i++) {
        if ((formInputElements[i].type == "radio") && (formInputElements[i].name == field) && (formInputElements[i].checked)) {
            alert(formInputElements[i].value + ' you got a value');     
            return formInputElements[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#n" name="theForm" id="yourFormId">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const radiopropertys = document.querySelectorAll('#property');//Id or Class

            radiopropertys.forEach(radioproperty => {
                if (radioproperty.value != '' && radioproperty.checked) {
                    //do something
                }
            })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -6):

```
    var value = $('input:radio[name="radiogroupname"]:checked').val();
```