# Display message including the session name

Tags: php, html

Is there a way, when clicking on a button, using HTML and PHP, to display an alert message containing the name of the session started, a radio button checked and the date and time choose? The button is included in a form, so I am looking if there is way to get these things done...

Here's my code:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

echo $_SESSION["uname"]; ?>

</div>

<br>

<form id="form1" action="welcome.php" method="post" >

    Blood Type Needed :
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="input1" type="Radio" value="A+" name="bn"/> A

    <input id="input1" type="Radio" value="B+" name="bn"/> B

   <input type="hidden" id="sessionId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>" />

$('input[@name="bn"]:checked').val();

var radios = document.getElementsByName('bn');

if (radios.checked) {
    function showSession(){


 var x=document.getElementById("sessionId");


var y=new Date();


 alert(x.value+" wants "+radios.value+y);

}
}

            </script>
                 <input id="done" class="button1" type="button" onClick="showSession();"  value="   DONE   ">


            </form>
```

Comment: javascript has no concept of, and couldn't care less about PHP sessions. If you want JS to be able to display PHP session state, you will have to have some mechanism of TELLING js that a session's been started, e.g.   `session_start(); echo 'var started = true';`?> inside a js `<script>` block.

Comment: You can do this through ajax, make an ajax request to the file containing the session code and depending on the respond populate your check boxes and text boxes using javascript....look for jquery ajax() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use a INPUT hidden and a javascript function, after attack it to onClick event on your button, but suggest you use Jquery to make all cross-browser:

**HTML input**

```
<input type="hidden" id="sessionId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showSession(){
   var x=document.getElementById("sessionId");
   alert(x.value);
}
```

**HTML BUTTON**

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="showSession();" />
```

**FULL SCRIPT**

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    echo "Session ID: ".$_SESSION["uname"]; 
?>
</div><br/>
<script>
    function showData(){
        var sessionId = document.getElementById("sessionId").value;
        var today = new Date();
        var x = document.getElementsByName('bn')
        var selected = false;
        // Check the selected value

        for(var k=0;k<x.length;k++)
          if(x[k].checked){
            alert(' '+ sessionId + " wants " + x[k].value + " " +today);
            selected = true;
          }
        if (!selected) alert('Select something please...');
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" action="welcome.php" method="post" ><br/>
    Blood Type Needed :<br/><br/>
    <input id="AP" type="Radio" value="A+" name="bn"/><label for="AP"> A</label><br/>
    <input id="BP" type="Radio" value="B+" name="bn"/><label for="BP"> B</label><br/><br/>
    <input id="done" type="button" onClick="showData();" value="   DONE   " class="button1">
    <input type="hidden" id="sessionId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: man your code worked for me but how can i add the value of the radio button checked and the date and time in the alert box ?

Comment: @Charbel this get the DATE var date=new Date(); and check this to get the value of a radio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Comment: can you please check my edited question please ? beacuse it gives me undefined in place of the radio button value

Comment: Try this: var radioValue = document.getElementById('input1').value;

Comment: it worked, but i always get the value of the first radio button :s

Comment: Try change the id of the radio, but don't touch the name like this:  <input id="APlus" type="Radio" value="A+" name="bn"/><input id="BPlus" type="Radio" value="B+" name="bn"/> B

Comment: if you have JQuery use this: $('input:radio[name=bn]:checked').val()

Comment: and what does this can help me ? i mean what can i do after doing that ?

Comment: an okay, i will try it now

Comment: i got in the alert message [object NodeList] if you want heres my javascript : $('input:radio[name=bn]:checked').val()

var radios = document.getElementsByName('bn');
    if (radios.checked) {
        function showSession(){
   var x=document.getElementById("sessionId");
   var y=new Date();
   alert(x.value+" wants "+radios.value+". Updated At "+y);

    }
}

Comment: don't worry ja,ja,ja.. Im making script to you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using simple Javascript

```
<script>
   function showValue()
   {
       var sessionVal=<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>;
       var selectedDate=documnet.form1.dt.value;
       var selectedRadio=document.form1.bn.value;
       alert(sessionVal+" "+selectedRadio+" "+selectedDate); //what ever format you want to show.
       document.form1.actiom='welcome.php';
       document.form1.submit();
   }
 </script>
```

In your html add onsubmit function

```
  <form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="return showValue();" method="post" >
```

Comment: i think your code is logic, but it didint work for me :s , i tried to put type="button" it was the same thing

Comment: and what about the button ? i keep it like this  <input id="done" class="button1" type="submit" value="   DONE   "> ?

Comment: the same thing, nothing happens when i click on the button :s