# How do I validate radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I have some radio buttons that I need to validate without using jquery.

```
if(document.getElementById('GCSE').checked){
examLevel = "GCSE";
}
if(document.getElementById('AS').checked){
examLevel = "AS";
}
if(document.getElementById('A2').checked){
examLevel = "A2";
```

This is what I have tried but doesn't work.

Comment: try if(document.getElementById('GCSE').checked=="checked")

Comment: Does your elements have correct ids?

Comment: [Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618826/402037)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it might be more effective:

```
if ( ( >>your radiobutton names<<.examLevel[0].checked == false ) && ( >>your radiobutton names<<.examLevel[1].checked == false )  && ( >>your radiobutton names<<.examLevel[2].checked == false ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('GCSE').checked==TRUE){
examLevel = "GCSE";
}
```