# How can I transform my this js code so that every property of an object get updated by an input value and radio button value?

Tags: javascript

I have an `object` with 3 properties `(amount,date,type)` .every time the object is called date updates automatically. Here is the code

```
var Transaction = function(amount, type) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.type = type;
    this.date = (function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var month = d.getMonth() +1;
        if (minutes<10) {
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + minutes);
        } else {
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + minutes);
        }
    })();
```

How can I set it up so that `amount` can receive the value of an html input field and `type` the value from radio buttons? I want to use pure JS

Comment: What have you tried? FYI, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript) shows how to get the value of a radio button. You can get the value of an input field with `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

If an input field is passed it will take it's value otherwise just use the value passed

```
this.amount = amount.value || amount;
this.type = type.value || type;
```