# Form radio button validation with background color change if not selected

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I have following validation working for text field

```
function check(){

    var flag = 0;
    if(document.form1.namef.value == ""){
        document.form1.namef.style.backgroundColor='#FF9ECE';
        flag = 1;
    }
    else{
        document.form1.namef.style.backgroundColor='';
    }if(flag){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have a form with gender which is not working in validation

```
<th width="222">Gender<font size="1" color="red">*</font></th>
                    <td width="253"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="0">Male<input type="radio" name="sex" value="1">Female</td>
```

How can I validate radio button in the function check()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript ... Follow this to get the radio button value, then just do whatever you need to do..

Comment: Why not have `flag` as a boolean and return that?