# HTML form with javascript gets "NaN" in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am by no means a programmer but I managed to get this to work in Chrome but I get "NaN" when I try it on IE (11 if that matters). 
It basically takes 4 criteria and does some math to give a price quote.Can anyone help with this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>instant inspection quote tool</title>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">

function calculateFee(frm){

   var building     = frm.building.value
   var distance     = frm.distance.value
   var age          = frm.age.value
   var sqft         = frm.sqft.value
   var total        = 0

   building = Number(building)
   distance = Number(distance)
   age      = Number(age)
   sqft     = Number(sqft)
   total    = Number(total)

   total = building + distance + age + sqft
   frm.total.value = total

}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<h1>Inspection Fee Calculator</h1>

<form method="post" action="">

Select the type of home
          <br><input type="radio" name="building" value="375"> detached
          <br><input type="radio" name="building" value="350"> semi-detached
          <br><input type="radio" name="building" value="350"> condo or freehold townhome - end unit
          <br><input type="radio" name="building" value="325"> condo or freehold townhome - interior unit
          <br><input type="radio" name="building" value="299"> condo apartment

<br><br>Is the home within 50 kms of Ottawa?   
          <br><input type="radio" name="distance" value="0"> yes
          <br><input type="radio" name="distance" value="25"> no

<br><br>Is the home less than 50 years old?    
          <br><input type="radio" name="age" value="0"> yes
          <br><input type="radio" name="age" value="25"> no

<br><br>Is the home less than 2000 square feet?    
          <br><input type="radio" name="sqft" value="0"> yes
          <br><input type="radio" name="sqft" value="25"> no
<br><br>

<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate Fee" onClick="calculateFee(this.form)"> 

<table>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Total Inspection fee:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="total" size="30" maxlength="30">
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `console.log(building, distance, age, sqft);` Which one is not a number? Also makes no sense to be converting the total. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Comment: Number will return NaN if you pass it something that is not a number. 
Perhaps it does not like the radiogroup.value but wants the value of the selected radio instead

Comment: You're relying on `form.name`, which is a bad idea, and doesn't seem to return the elements in IE

Comment: You will need to loop through the radio buttons in each group, see which one is `checked`, and then get the `value` of that specific element.

Comment: More correctly, IE returns a collection of elements, not a single element, so `frm.building[0].value` solves it in IE (somewhat, it still doesn't get the checked one), but it's still not a good idea.

Comment: adeneo your first comment is wrong, your second is what I said. in jQUery it is simple: `var building  = $('input[name=building]:checked', '#myForm').val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - note: querySelector and  querySelectorAll do not work in IE < 8 and in 8 only in standards mode

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3fL6mdsg/)

```
function calculateFee(frm) {
  var total = 0,
      rads  = frm.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); // get all checked radios
  for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++) {
    var num = Number(rads[i].value);
    total += isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
  }
  frm.total.value = total;
}
```

For individual radio values use the name - however getting the value directly it will fail if the radio is not checked

```
var building = frm.querySelector("input[name=building]:checked");
if (building) total += Number(building.value);
```

To validate, hook up the form's onsubmit

```
function validate(frm) {
  var rads  = frm.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); // get all checked radios
  if (rads.length<4) {
    alert("Please select one of each");
    return false; // cancel form
  }
  return true;
}    
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=function() {
    return validate(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the values are "checked" off then the values are undefined try adding this...

```
function getRadioValue( radioElement ){
    for (var i=0; i < radioElement.length; i++){
       if ( radioElement[i].checked ){
          return radioElement[i].value;
       }
    }
}
```

Replace previous code with this...

```
 var building     = getRadioValue( frm.building ) || 0;
   var distance     = getRadioValue( frm.distance ) || 0;
   var age          = getRadioValue( frm.age ) || 0;
   var sqft         = getRadioValue( frm.sqft ) || 0;
   var total        = 0
```

Comment: Nope. You need a helper function to get the value of a radio collection in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var building     = frm.querySelector("[name=building]:checked");
var distance     = frm.querySelector("[name=distance]:checked");
var age          = frm.querySelector("[name=age]:checked");
var sqft         = frm.querySelector("[name=sqft]:checked");

building = (building && building.value) || 0;
distance = (distance && distance.value) || 0;
age = (age && age.value) || 0;
sqft = (sqft && sqft.value) || 0;
```

Comment: This will fail if the radio is NOT checked

Comment: I want them to have to select one from each anyway. Selecting just one field is going to give an incorrect quote. Is there an easy addition to check for that?

Comment: Yes - see my suggestion.