# Getting Radio Buttons to output info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I am very new to coding and CS and so sorry if this question is kind of obvious. I couldn't really find anything about this before that I understood. I am making a set of radio buttons and I would like the user to check off what applies to them and submit it. How do I get the value of the button (with javascript) that they click so that my code could generate a corresponding output.

```
        <p> Pick a hair length </p>

        <input type="hidden" value="" id="rdValue" />

        <div>
            <label> <input type="radio" name="length" value="short"> Short </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> <input type="radio" name="length" value="med"> Medium </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><input type="radio" name="length" value="long"> Long </label>
        </div>

        <p> Pick a hair type </p>

        <div>
            <label> <input type="radio" name="type" value="curly"> Curly </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> <input type="radio" name="type" value="wavy"> Wavy </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="straight"> Straight </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: please clarify further what it is you're trying to do. there's way too many ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: also, this might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the value for the selected radio button from the "length" radio buttons for example:

> $("input:radio[name='length']").val();

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript) is very similar to yours, and has answers in jQuery and Javascript. It's pretty simple.

Basically, you get the DOM elements of the radio buttons from the page, then loop through them checking their values. Once you find one that is "true", you've found the selected value.