# how to store radio button value in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(form1) 
{
  if (document.getElementById('agent').checked)
  {
    alert("agent") // works
    var agent1=document.getElementById('agent').value;
    alert(agent1)  // does not work
  }
  if (document.getElementById('holding').checked)
  {
    var holding=document.getElementById('holding').value;
  }
  if(agent1=="agent" && holding=="holding")
  {
    alert("hiii") // does not work
  }
}
```

My form is like this:

```
<form id="form-validation" method="post" name="form1" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="direct" value="direct" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='none';return true;" ><span>Direct</span>
  <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="agent" value="agent" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='';return true;" onfocus="document.getElementById('agent').clicked"><span>Agent</span> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_username">Reservation Status<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="H" onClick="holdingRadionButtonClicked()" id="holding" checked> Holding 
      <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="C" onClick="confirmRadionButtonClicked()" id="confirm"> Confirm
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-primary " value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

What I want is that when I click the submit button the value of the radio button has to be stored in the variable.

When I tried to get the control, that worked but when I tried to get the value, it does not.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Comment: yeah i looked into it...but wats went wrong in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is mainly scoping. You declare variables inside a scope, `{ scope }`, and then try to access them outside of this scope. This will not work.

```
if (1 == 1) {
    var x = true;
}
document.write(x);
```

The above code would not print out `true`, but rather `undefined` since the `x` only lives within `if (1 == 1) { }`.

So, declare your variables like this:

```
var x;
if (1 == 1) {
    x = true;
}
document.write(x);
```

This will work since `x` is declared for the entire outer scope or function.

Below is an example with your code, just fixing the variable declarations:

```js
// this will check the checked radio in a group, and return the value
function getCheckedValue(el) {
  for (var i = 0, length = el.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (el[i].checked) {
      return el[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
  return '';
}

function validate(form1) {
  var checkedbooking = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('booking_type'));
  var checkedreservation = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('reservation_status'));
  if (agent1 == "agent" && holding == "H") {
    alert('everything works');
  }
}

function validate(form1) {
  var agent1 = '';
  var holding = '';
  if (document.getElementById('agent').checked) {
    agent1 = document.getElementById('agent').value;
    alert(agent1)
  }
  if (document.getElementById('holding').checked) {
    holding = document.getElementById('holding').value;
  }
  if (agent1 == "agent" && holding == "H") {
    alert('everything works');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form-validation" method="post" name="form1" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="direct" value="direct" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='none';return true;"><span>Direct</span>
    <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="agent" value="agent" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='';return true;" onfocus="document.getElementById('agent').clicked"><span>Agent</span> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_username">Reservation Status<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="H" onClick="holdingRadionButtonClicked()" id="holding" checked>Holding
        <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="C" onClick="confirmRadionButtonClicked()" id="confirm">Confirm
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-primary " value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**I have a suggested improvement to the code though**, as can be seen below. This will use the group name of the radios instead, as it was intended, and check for a selected value by looping through the collection (by using a custom function; `getcheckedValue()`). In the long run this will make your code much more compact and less error-prone.

```js
// this will check the checked radio in a group, and return the value
function getCheckedValue(el) {
  for (var i = 0, length = el.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (el[i].checked) {
      return el[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function validate(form1) {
  var checkedbooking = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('booking_type'));
  var checkedreservation = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('reservation_status'));
  if (checkedbooking && checkedreservation) {
    alert('I selected "' + checkedbooking + '" and "' + checkedreservation + '"');
  } else {
    alert('Oops, you forgot to select something');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form-validation" method="post" name="form1" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="direct" value="direct" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='none';return true;"><span>Direct</span>
    <input type="radio" name="booking_type" id="agent" value="agent" onclick="document.getElementById('hidethis').style.display='';return true;" onfocus="document.getElementById('agent').clicked"><span>Agent</span> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_username">Reservation Status<span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="H" onClick="holdingRadionButtonClicked()" id="holding" checked>Holding
        <input type="radio" name="reservation_status" value="C" onClick="confirmRadionButtonClicked()" id="confirm">Confirm
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-primary " value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @ram Good. See my updated code also for a bit more compact code.

Comment: yeah the snippet code thats wat i'm mentioning...y i can't get it right from my code...what went wrong...is it necessary to declare variable outside the function...

Comment: @ram not outside the function, but in the same level as you want to use it. As it is, you've declared them inside if-statements, so they will only be available there. I hope you can see from my code examples in my answer. There is a working snippet with your code in it too. But I would suggest you use my _suggested code_ at the bottom instead.