# javascript conditional onclick form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I cannot use JQuery for this project.

I am trying to gather 3 variables from 3 radio buttons. The submission of this form will trigger a function that will check the three variables with a simple conditional. This will either run the first line or (else) run the second line of code. I'm having a problem with the conditional (it appears). I always get the first line to fire, never the second line.

```js
function valid() {
  var q1 = document.getElementById("ques1").value;
  var q2 = document.getElementById("ques2").value;
  var q3 = document.getElementById("ques3").value;
  if (q1 ==="5" && q2 ==="5" && q3 ==="5" ) {
    alert("Thank you for your interest in acme employment. We are not able to consider you for employment at this time. ");
  } else {
    window.location.assign("http://acmeemployment.com");
    //window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="">

  <p>Are you 18 years of age or older?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="ques1" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="7">No
  </p>

  <p>Are you willing to take a drug screen according to our policy?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ques2" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="7">No
  </p>

  <p>Will you release your background information inclusive of ciminal records?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="ques3" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="7">No
  </p>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="valid()" />

</form>
```

Comment: You have to check if they're actually checked, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Comment: You want to check `var q1_yes = document.getElementById("ques1").checked` which is different from returning the `value`; the `value` will always be the same.  Also, you have at least one typo on the word "criminal".

Comment: Thank you for the reference Tom. I wasn't able to find this on my initial search. Very helpful! Also, Marc, very useful. I was piggybacking someone else's code and overlooked the "value" versus "checked" - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't checking for the selected radio buttons. You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the selected radio buttons.

Also, it seems like your logic is backwards and you want to check for `!== "5"`.

```js
function valid() {
  var q1 = document.querySelector("[name='q1']:checked").value;
  var q2 = document.querySelector("[name='q2']:checked").value;
  var q3 = document.querySelector("[name='q3']:checked").value;
  if (q1 ==="5" && q2 ==="5" && q3 ==="5" ) {
    console.log("Thank you for your interest in acme employment. We are not able to consider you for employment at this time. ");
  } else {
    console.log("redirect to http://acmeemployment.com");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">

  <p>Are you 18 years of age or older?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="ques1" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="7">No
  </p>

  <p>Are you willing to take a drug screen according to our policy?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="ques2" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="7">No
  </p>

  <p>Will you release your background information inclusive of ciminal records?*<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="ques3" value="5">Yes
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="7">No
  </p>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="valid()" />

</form>
```

Comment: This is the good answer, but an explanation is better... maybe OP doesn't knows that radio buttons has the value even if not checked

Comment: Thank you Dave. I appreciate the effort and insight. This worked very well.
Marcos, I'm able to check the script from http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.js and learn from that (even though it's pretty big for this specific task).

Comment: @Graham I'm glad I could help. Don't be confused by the console.js include. That is only used to show results in the snippet--it doesn't have anything to do with the actual solution.