# Create radio button inside dynamic generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in Ajax/Javascript where I am generating a dynamic table that should hold some returned value.
At the beggining of each row I would like to have a column of radio buttons, that I could use to identify a particular row.
How can I create radio buttons inside the table?
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controller_data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');


    // this is the row where the radio button should be

    tr.append("<td> <input type="radio"> </td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].question + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].image + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer1 + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer2 + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer3 + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer4 + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
}
```

Comment: OK. I have managed to create them by escaping the quotes, but they don't seem to work together as they are not inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

Doing only two rows, it would look like this...

```
     tr.append("<td><input name='question1'  type='radio' value='" + controller_data[i].answer1  + "'/>"+ controller_data[i].answer1  + "</td>");
     tr.append("<td><input name='question1'  type='radio' value='" + controller_data[i].answer2  + "'/>"+ controller_data[i].answer2  + "</td>");
```

it is the radio button name that groups raido buttons. Also, you go back and fourth between single and double quotes as I did, you do not have to do as much escaping.
Also, I put in the answer in the value but if you have an answer id, that would actually be the value to put there.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the name='radiobutton' and now they work together. If I add an id that will hold the value of [i], would I be able to know which radio button I have selected?

Comment: Cause I am to lazy to type it out, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

Just remove `double quotes` and replace it with `single quotes`, otherwise it will treat `radio`    as a variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < controller_data.length; i++) {
tr = $('<tr/>');


// this is the row where the radio button should be
//CHANGE BELOW
tr.append("<td> <input type='radio'> </td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].id + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].question + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].image + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer1 + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer2 + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer3 + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + controller_data[i].answer4 + "</td>");
$('table').append(tr);
```

}