# JavaScript: how to populate radio button value and label with variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am afraid this is a beginner's question that should have been answered already, but either it is not or I cannot articulate myself correctly... Please bear with me, I hope this has a quick solution:

I want to populate my radio buttons of my form with variables. Later I want to get the values from my google spreadsheet, but I am stuck with the variables already.

```
<body>
  <div>
      <h4>Main Page</h4>
        <fieldset style="background: #eceff9;"><legend style="padding: 10px;">Select Material</legend>
           <label><input type="radio" name="matPick" id="mat1"></label><br>
           <label><input type="radio" name="matPick" id="mat2" value="Material 2"> Material 2</label><br>
        </fieldset>
  </div>
```

```
(function() {
var mat1 = 'Material 1';
document.getElementById("mat1").innerHTML = mat1;
})();
```

I also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkw1/5mn6S/23/).

I hope the code explains what I want to achieve, basically the html should show similar to Material 2, but created with my javascript variable.

Thanks very much for Your help!
Martin

Comment: There are plenty of information in the internet, you could find answer within 5min of googling, Anyway this should help alot [Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618826/2308005)

Comment: Hi, thanks for all patient answers, I have been trying them out all evening today. @Medet, I try to assign a value to a radio button, not to read out the value. I am sure the difference is minor for a skilled programmer - well, I am afraid I am not ;-) . The Label of the button now gets displayed correctly in jsfiddle, but not in my google form. I am afraid Google sanitizes away the TextNode. Moreover, I neither can assign the VALUE to the button. Please see my fiddle for my current status of tinkering... http://jsfiddle.net/uzcd3cy2/

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers?fbclid=IwAR3tnMwVeqa2Dt4VvQE_HNQ_zgmfhK0EFDhAbLdfvW_54Msw_kwBtGRsJ-I)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the innerHTML of the input. This, of course, is invalid. You need to find the parent of the input then insert the text.

```
(function() {
    var mat1 = 'Material 1';
    var ele = document.getElementById("mat1").parentNode;
    ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mat1));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<body>
      <div>
          <h4>Main Page</h4>
            <fieldset style="background: #eceff9;"><legend style="padding: 10px;">Select Material</legend>
               <input type="radio" name="matPick"><label id="mat1"></label><br>
               <label><input type="radio" name="matPick" id="mat2" value="Material 2"> Material 2</label><br>
            </fieldset>
      </div>
</body>
```