# Checked checkbox and onclick redirect to another page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login form and a section with 3 checkboxes and a final submit button. I want to write code such that when a checkbox is checked, and the submit button is clicked, the user will be redirected to another page depending on which checkbox was checked.

I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">
```

I know that you can use

```
if (isset($_POST['male'])) {
    // Checkbox male is selected
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

To see if the checkbox is checked, and

```
 <input type="button" value="goElsewhere" class="GE" id="GELSEWHERE" 
  onClick="Javascript:window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';" />
```

For a page redirect when the button is clicked.

But I'm not sure how to combine these. How would I go about it?

Edit: The page should redirect only after the final submit button is clicked. The checkboxes should only determine which page the user is directed to. Checking a checkbox should not redirect the page.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male" id="male" >
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female" id="female" >

<input type="submit" onClick="redirect()">
```

Use client sided JS (more practical)

```
function redirect()
{
   if(document.getElementById("male").checked == true)
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
   else if(document.getElementById("female").checked == true)
        window.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';        
}
```

It may be more practical to use radio button not check boxes since only one option can be selected. Then you use a switch statement.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">
<input type="radio" name="female" value="Female">
```

Getting the chosen value is similar to jbabey's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript).

Another approach is to simply pass the URL in the function

```
 function redirect(url)
 {
    window.location.href = url;
 }
```

Then you would have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female" id="female" onClick="redirect('www.google.com')">
```

Comment: sorry, I've just started learning PHP so I'm a bit confused. I have a single PHP file with an HTML section, CSS style in the header, and PHP commands below everything. If I use javascript, can I input the redirect() function as is into my PHP file between <? php ?> ? Or do I have to make a separate JS file and reference it in my PHP file somehow?

Comment: I also want it so that the user is redirected on button click, not when a certain radio button is clicked. I'm not sure if your code does that

Comment: echo "<script>[insert javascript]</script>"; would do it if insisde <?php ?>. If inside regular HTML just put <script>[insert javascript]</script> directly.

having JS in a separate file is healthy programming but not for something this specific

Comment: @jvnna modified code to call function on submit click

Comment: @jvnna Any time. Please use radiobuttons not checkboxes and try to pick up JS then jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect with PHP, the method of doing so is as follows.

```
header("Location: http://url.com");
```

so:

```
if (isset($_POST['male'])) {
    header("Location: http://male-website.com");
    die(); // Stop from doing anything else
} else {
    header("Location: http://something-else.com");
    die(); // Stop from doing anything else
}
```

*Die is added as a safety precaution for any crawlers etc. that ignore header requests (stops anything else from happening.)*

But I'd do it with JS, as Moussa said.