# print or show current value of variable in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the below; I am attempting to capture form field contents on click of submit button. However when I go to test it and console.log the variable I just get the HTML of the form field. Any pointers. Or I get uncaught reference error, the variable is not defined.

*Mark-Up wise: I'm using input type text and input type radios.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

         $('#submitS').click(function(){

         var firstName01 = document.getElementById('firstName').value;

         var firstName02 = document.getElementById('firstName2').value;

         var lastName01 = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
         var lastName02 = document.getElementById('lastName2').value;

         var iphone01 = document.getElementById('iphone').value;
         var android01 = document.getElementById('android').value;

         var iphone02 = document.getElementById('iphone2').value;
         var android02 = document.getElementById('android2').value;
     });

});
```

Comment: What type are your inputs ?

Comment: To access radio buttons value, use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks... but my input text don't seem to work with the above as well...

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your code (HTML + JS) so we can see what you have ?

Comment: I would guess that you are using console.log in the wrong place. It won't work outside of the click event for example.

Comment: Why not use jquery all the way?

Comment: Can't find any `console.log` in your code.

Comment: Where are you printing them out from?  By declaring your variables as vars they are local to the function, if you remove the var keyword they will be available globally.

Comment: is your submit button id really "submitS"? it looks weird in my eyes for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.textContent` instead of .value