# Get the Value of Radiobutton Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Problem: I have not been able to get the value of a radiobutton or value in a textbox.

From trial and error, I found that the following gives me access to the information in div gender1

I could not figure out how to get the value of gender or age. I tried appending .value/.value(), using the id attribute, etc. I also tried various methods from a related question on stack overflow ([Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript)), but had little success.

```js
var checkedRadio = document.querySelectorAll('.w3-container')[0]
                        .querySelectorAll('#box')[0]
                     .querySelector('#gender1');

console.log( checkedRadio );
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <div id="box" style="width:600px;height:650px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;">
      <h5><b>Age (years):</b></h5>
      <div id="age">
        <input type="number" name="age1">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="gender1">
        <h5><b>Male or Female?</b>:
                    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
                    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
                </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use

```
document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value
```

to get the value.

```js
document.getElementById("btn_click").addEventListener("click", function(){

  
  if(document.querySelector('input[name="age1"]').value !== "" && document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked') !== null )
  {
  console.log("Age : ", document.querySelector('input[name="age1"]').value);
  console.log("Gender : ", document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value);
   }
  else
  {
    console.log("Please provide all the details.")
   }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <div id="box" style="width:600px;height:650px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;">
      <h5><b>Age (years):</b></h5>
      <div id="age">
        <input type="number" name="age1">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="gender1">
        <h5><b>Male or Female?</b>:
                    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" value="Male" > Male
                    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
                </h5>
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Deep! In testing this answer, however, it seems this requires one of the radio-buttons to be selected, otherwise it will return null. Am I correct in stating this?

Comment: @user2657817 does it matter? because when the page loads, the radio buttons will not be selected... Note that Deep has a `checked` attribute in `#r2`...

Comment: @user2657817 i have just modified the snippet to let user select values first and then print the list. Since the earlier snippet was printing the values on page load , i put a checked attribute iin the html itself as kukkuz explained.

Comment: Thanks Deep! Really appreciate it. One last thing, how would you suggest error checking/avoiding the type error if the user presses click with no data entered.

Comment: @user2657817 updated the snippet for a simple validation to check if user has provided both Age and Gender values.

Comment: It there any browser compatibility table for this solution? Is it cross-browser?

Comment: Since this is a vanilla JavaScript solution , it will work with all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *querySelector* to select the textbox *value* or the *value* of the *checked* radio button like this:

```
var age = document.querySelector('input[type=number][name=age1]').value;
var gender = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').value;
```

See demo below:

```js
function submit() {

  var age = document.querySelector('input[type=number][name=age1]').value;
  var gender = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').value;

  console.log(age, gender);

}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <div id="box" style="width:600px;height:650px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;">
    <h5><b>Age (years):</b></h5>
    <div id="age">
      <input type="number" name="age1">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="gender1">
      <h5><b>Male or Female?</b>:
                    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
                    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
                </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="submit()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: What happens if he has more than one radio selection in same page?

Comment: Ataur Rahman Munna, I think then you can just use a "name" argument instead of type in order to get the radio-button values.

Comment: kukkuz, thanks for your comment. Do you have any suggestions on how to address cases where the user presses Click me without providing the inputs?

Comment: Then you can update your answer as the answer is more specific.

Comment: @user2657817 you can add some validation... Deep has added that to his answer I guess...

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript onclick event.
Please look in to the below example,

```
<script>
function getGender(gender) {
  alert(gender);
}
</script>    
<body>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <div id="box" style="width:600px;height:650px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;">
                <h5><b>Age (years):</b></h5>
                <div id="age"><input type="number" name="age1"><br></div>
                <div id="gender1">
                    <h5><b>Male or Female?</b>:
                        <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" onclick = "getGender(this.value)" value="Male"> Male
                        <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" onclick = "getGender(this.value)" value="Female"> Female
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

OR

```
<script>
function getValues() {
  // Get value of selected radio button
  var genderVal;
  if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
    genderVal = document.getElementById('r1').value;
  } else if (document.getElementById('r2').checked) {
    genderVal = document.getElementById('r2').value;
  }

  alert("Value of textbox:"+ document.getElementsByName("age1")[0].value+" Value of radio button:"+ genderVal);
}
</script>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <div id="box" style="width:600px;height:650px;padding:10px;border:2px solid black;">
          <h5><b>Age (years):</b></h5>
          <div id="age"><input type="number" name="age1"><br></div>
          <div id="gender1">
            <h5><b>Male or Female?</b>:
              <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" onclick = "getGender(this.value)" value="Male"> Male
              <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" onclick = "getGender(this.value)" value="Female"> Female
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="button" value="GetValues" onclick="getValues()">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Hope the above examples are helpful to you.