# Script for pulling ID and Value from selected radio button not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pull both the `id` and `value` from a selected radio button.  I came across this style of code in a few posts and blogs I came across and decided to give it a shot in Angular 2.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        alert(radios[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
 }
```

This is an excerpt from here [Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript)

The way I'm trying to implement it in my Angular class is like this

```
selected = {value1: '', value2: ''}; //where I want the results to be stored.

//custom function with the snippet implemented
getSelected() {
    const radios = document.getElementsByName(this.quesForm.value.name);

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].click){
            this.selected.value1 = radios[i].getAttribute("id");
            this.selected.value2 = radios[i].getAttribute("value");
            break;
        }
    }
}

//calling it here in an attempt to make sure it detects when the selection changes.
ngOnChanges() {
    this.getSelected();
    console.log(this.selected);
}
```

my template is set up like this

```
<div *ngFor="let ans of quesForm.value.answers">
    <input type="radio" 
        [attr.name]  = "quesForm.value.name" 
        [attr.id]    = "ans.id"
        [attr.value] = "ans.answer"
    />
    <label>{{ans.answer}}</label>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not seeing any results log, I also have this outside of the `form` tag to show results as well which stays empty.

```
<p>{{selected | json}}</p>
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data binding and DOM events like:

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let ans of quesForm.value.answers">
    <input type="radio" 
        [attr.name]  = "quesForm.value.name" 
        [attr.id]    = "ans.id"
        [attr.value] = "ans.answer"
        (click)="selectAnswer(ans)"
    />
    <label>{{ans.answer}}</label>
</div>
```

Component:

```
selectAnswer(ans) {
    this.selected = ans;
    console.log(this.selected);
}
```

In Angular 2 accessing the DOM directly is [generally bad practice](http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) and usually indicates a problem with your design.

Comment: How do I make that grab the value and ID from the selected input?

Comment: It's in the answer object