# When creating a list of radio buttons, how do you make it to where there is only 1 "correct" answer?

Tags: html

I am relatively new to this, but i am trying to create a list of options to choose from, and i font want any but one of the options to allow the user to continue. Like when you put a requirement on a password, is there a way to put a requirement as  to which Radio button can be allowed to be selected? Like "Wrong answer" pops up until they select the correct answer. Any tips or referrals would be appreciated.

Here is what i got so far.

```
<p>Whats an aliens hobby?</p>
<form>
    <label for="skiing">Skiing:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="hobbychoice">

    <label for="murder">murder:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="hobbychoice" incorrect>

    <label for="hecking and general computer owning skills">hecking and general computer owning skills:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="hobbychoice"  correctanswer>
    <button>Check Answer</button>
```

Comment: please post your attempts of source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you solve this with javascript or after submission with php.

You can give your submit button a "onsubmit" and then check the value of your radio button group. If the wrong answer got selected, you show an alert or make a text box visible.

[Get Radio Button Value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript)

Or you validate the data with php if this is available. But the site has to be submitted first.