# How to access the value of a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the value of a radio button using HTML and Javascript to make a simple quiz but it does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```js
function check() {
var a = document.getElementById("test").value
if (a === "one") {
alert("Correct!")
} else {
alert("Wrong!")
}
}
```

```html
<h1><center>Simple Quiz</center></h1>
<br>
1) What is 1 + 1?
<br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test" value="one">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test" value="two">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test" value="three">3<br>
  <button onclick="check()">Check</button>
</form>
```

It always says "Correct!" even when it is not. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You have the same id for all 3 radio buttons

Comment: You can't use the same id for multiple elements.

Comment: Also, use checked property to see if radio button is selected and then read the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected radio button’s value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points you are missing:

- An id must be **unique** on the whole page
- To check if a radio button is checked, use its `checked` attribute

```js
function check() {
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  if (two.checked) {
    alert("Correct!")
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!")
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <center>Simple Quiz</center>
</h1>
<br> 1) What is 1 + 1?
<br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="one" value="one">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="two" value="two">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="three" value="three">3<br>
  <button onclick="check()">Check</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot have the same **id** on multiple elements. Make to give your elements a unique **id** and if you need to give them all the same style you could use `class` instead.

Instead of checking the `value` of the radio button, you should check whether the radio button is `checked`.

Take a look at the example below.

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById('test2').checked) {
    alert('correct');
  } else {
    alert('wrong');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><center>Simple Quiz</center></h1>
<br>
1) What is 1 + 1?
<br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test1" value="one">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test2" value="two">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="one" id="test3" value="three">3<br>
  <button onclick="check()">Check</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not define more than one element with the same id that's a bad practice, you could improve your code `function check() { 
  for (elemnt of document.getElementByClassName('test') ) { if (element.checked ) alert('correct');
else alert ("incrrect");}}` 
Them in the html you can do this

`<input type="radio" class="test" value="1">`

`<input type="radio" class="test" value="2">`

`<input type="radio" class="test" value="3">`