# Javascript variable in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

I'm creating a process which pulls down a static Google map image using their API.

I have a form which has radio buttons with the following map image options:

```
 Satellite
 Roadmap
 Hybrid
 Terrain
```

The radio buttons are in a form - part of which is below:

```
<summary>Basemap</summary>
<div class="group">
    <p>Select a Map Style:</p>
    <p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle" value="Satellite" checked /> Satellite</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle" value="Roadmap"/> Roadmap</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle" value="Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle" value="Terrain" /> Terrain</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have an underlying javascript document which is called from the html page.

It contains the following code:

```
var bmStyle = document.getElementById("basemapStyle").value;

if (bmStyle = "Satellite" ) {       
    var basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}
else if (bmStyle = "Roadmap" ) {        
    var basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}
else if (bmStyle = "Hybrid" )  {        
    var basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}
else if (bmStyle = "Terrain" )  {       
    var basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}
```

The page loads successfully and a "basemap" is generated.  However, the selected radio button makes no difference and the only first variable in the if else statement seems to get loaded.

I feel there's some logic error in the if else statement but I can't seem to get my head round it.

Comment: Declare `var basemapStyle` outside of your `if` statements. You're into scope issues. Also you're using an `assignment operate` in your `if` statements, use `==` or `===`.

Comment: You have multiple elements with same id, that is not allowed in html.

Comment: You can't use multiple Ids with the same name.

Comment: Both you can have and is allowed to have duplicate IDs but getElementsById() will always return the first.

Comment: @Alex There are no scope issues as var declarations get hoisted. But it does not look pretty, though.

Comment: @mbuechmann thanks for pointing that out. I completely forgot about hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign different ids to the form elements:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle_Satellite" value="Satellite" checked /> Satellite</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle_Roadmap" value="Roadmap"/> Roadmap</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle_Hybrid" value="Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle_Terrain" value="Terrain" /> Terrain</label>
```

Set the default value to the first value. Then check all other form elements:

```
var basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
if (document.getElementById('basemapStyle_Roadmap').checked) {
    basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
} else if (document.getElementById('basemapStyle_Hybrid').checked) {
    basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
} else if (document.getElementById('basemapStyle_Terrain').checked) {
    basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
You have this in your conditional:

> if (bmStyle = "Satellite")

Instead you should use:

> if (bmStyle == "Satellite")

```
if (bmStyle == "Satellite" ) {       
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Roadmap" ) {        
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Hybrid" )  {        
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Terrain" )  {       
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
```

**Second:**
IDs should be unique, so you must change it.

**Solution on your code (using duplicated IDs)**:

```
var bmStyle = $('#basemapStyle:checked').val()


if (bmStyle == "Satellite" ) {       
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Roadmap" ) {        
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Hybrid" )  {        
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
    else if (bmStyle == "Terrain" )  {       
        var basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
        }
```

Comment: Why not `===`? Triple equals are always preferred

Comment: `==` automatically converts types if the operands aren't the same type. `===` uses strict comparison. Read [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: @Alex I know, for sure in this case == will run. Maybe === is the correct one. But the real problem was that his code was using equals instead of comparing

Comment: This still won't work as all radio boxes have the same id.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same id for different elements.

So:

```
var bmStyle = document.getElementById("basemapStyle").value;
```

is not returning what you expect. Check it by adding this line:

```
alert(bmStyle);
```

So remove the id's.

Read more here how to get radio value:

[How to get the selected radio button’s value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value)

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you have Assignment = in if instead of ==
2. You have to declare basemapStyle outsite
3. You cannot use same id to all your radio buttons
   Here i have redesigned Your Code To Get A Proper Output using Function

```js
function fun(radio){
var bmStyle = radio.value; 

  var basemapStyle;
  if (bmStyle == "Satellite" )
             basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
            
        else if (bmStyle == "Roadmap" )       
             basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
           
        else if (bmStyle == "Hybrid" )      
             basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
           
        else if (bmStyle == "Terrain" )      
             basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
alert(basemapStyle);      
 }
```

```html
<summary>Basemap</summary>
<div class="group">
<p>Select a Map Style:</p>
<p>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle"  value="Satellite" checked onclick=fun(this) /> Satellite</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle"  value="Roadmap" onclick=fun(this) /> Roadmap</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" value="Hybrid" onclick=fun(this) /> Hybrid</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle"  value="Terrain" onclick=fun(this) /> Terrain</label>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple if statements, you should **store** all the **data** in an **object** an retrieve the values from there. And as already mentioned, an id must be unique. So use classes instead.

#### Example

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll(".basemapStyle");
var basemapStyle = "";

var bmStyles = {
  "Satellite": "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx",
  "Roadmap": "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx",
  "Hybrid": "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx",
  "Terrain": "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx"
}

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i += 1) {
  var radio = radios[i];
  if (radio.checked === true) {
    basemapStyle = bmStyles[radio.value];
    console.log(basemapStyle);
  }
}
```

```html
<summary>Basemap</summary>
<div class="group">
  <p>Select a Map Style:</p>
  <p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" class="basemapStyle" value="Satellite"  /> Satellite</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" class="basemapStyle" value="Roadmap" /> Roadmap</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" class="basemapStyle" value="Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" class="basemapStyle" value="Terrain" checked/> Terrain</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a single attribute of type ID per element.

Check out [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10)

Comment: you need to post the relevant parts of the W3C link for this answer to stay relevant if their content changes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have used an `Assignment Operator` [`=`] in your `if` statement.

Instead, you have to use a `Comparison Operator` [`==`] or [`===`].

This means that your code `if (bmStyle = "Satellite")` should be `if (bmStyle == "Satellite" )`

Read about this on [`W3 JavaScript Operators Reference`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp).

---

Secondly, you have assigned the same `ID` to all of your radio buttons; you can't do that. `ID's` are made to make the element unique.

---

Thirdly, it's neater to assign your `basemapStyle` variable outside of the if statements like so:

---

```js
// Specify all radio buttons by their 'Unique ID'
var bmStyle1 = document.getElementById("basemapStyle1").value;
var bmStyle2 = document.getElementById("basemapStyle2").value;
var bmStyle3 = document.getElementById("basemapStyle3").value;
var bmStyle4 = document.getElementById("basemapStyle4").value;

// Declared outside
var basemapStyle;

if (bmStyle1 == "Satellite") {
  basemapStyle = "&maptype=satellite&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
} else if (bmStyle2 == "Roadmap") {
  basemapStyle = "&maptype=roadmap&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
} else if (bmStyle3 == "Hybrid") {
  basemapStyle = "&maptype=hybrid&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
} else if (bmStyle4 == "Terrain") {
  basemapStyle = "&maptype=terrain&scale=4&format=png32&key=xxxx";
}

console.log(basemapStyle);
```

```html
<summary>Basemap</summary>
<div class="group">
  <p>Select a Map Style:</p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle1" value="Satellite" checked /> Satellite</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle2" value="Roadmap"/> Roadmap</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle3" value="Hybrid" /> Hybrid</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="basemapStyle" id="basemapStyle4" value="Terrain" /> Terrain</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Follow this [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/1s2d0eyb/) link to see an updated and optimized version.

Comment: `basemapstyle` does not have the be declared outside the if statement. The variable gets hoisted. But it does not look pretty, though.

Comment: Yeah, I guess in this case it just looks prettier. :)

Comment: And it's a good practice to declare your variables at the top of the scope.

Comment: I completely agree. :)