# Radio buttons returning final value in list

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

relatively new to both JS (apps script) and HTML

Please can you help- I have a form that is generally submitting perfectly (text boxes, date box) but the radio is always selecting the final value. Here is the HTML (bootstrap CSS, got from a template site) and JS to gather the data at the end-

```
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="ST0">
  <input type="radio" name="STRating" id="ST0" value="1">
  1
</label> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="ST1">
  <input type="radio" name="STRating" id="ST1" value="2">
  2
</label> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="ST2">
  <input type="radio" name="STRating" id="ST2" value="3" checked="checked">
  3
</label> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="ST S">
  <input type="radio" name="STRating" id="ST3" value="4">
  4
</label> 
<label class="radio-inline" for="ST4">
  <input type="radio" name="STRating" id="ST4" value="5">
  5
</label>
```

And the Apps script

```
 function testing143(){
var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
var obj ={};
for(var i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++){
    var item = form.item(i);
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
}
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).testing143(obj);
```

Comment: Is `testing143` a client-side function? If that's the case, you shouldn't call it via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run): that's for calling server-side functions (from `.gs` files). If it's a server-side function, things like `document.getElementById("myForm")` cannot work. Could you please clarify this? What are you submitting the form anyway?

Comment: Hi- I may have run into an issue down the line which you were forewarning...

Would you be able to review my latest post? I am trying to submit data to a sheet from a dialog window via an HTML form

heres the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701249/sheets-not-executing-function-fully-for-non-owner-i-e-editor

Answer (score 2):

All the five elements of the radio buttons share the same name, hence your code reassigns five times a value to `obj['STRating']`, and the last assignment (5) is what you get.
Instead of doing the unconditional assignment

```
obj[item.name] = item.value;
```

You should condition the assignment only for the checked button, like that:

```
if (item.checked) obj[item.name] = item.value;
```

This way you still pass through all five buttons, but you memorize only the value of the checked one.

Comment: Many thanks for this- and then to take the values from the other items which do not have a checked/unchecked value? Imagine I need an else if which i've tried like the below but now still getting 5 for the STRating...

        if (item.checked) obj[item.name] = item.value;
        else if (item.unchecked);
        else;
        obj[item.name] = item.value;

Comment: No, it must be an "if" without "else". You ignore the unchecked items, and memorize only the value of the checked one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a named array and you have five elements with the same name "STRating". The last loop will set it to "5".

I think you need more like the selected value. More Infos: [How to get the selected radio button’s value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value)