# How Do I Render Radio Buttons Individually With WTForms?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to have a form with a set of radio buttons, with each radio button controlling enablement of several other controls, and I want the other controls to be interspersed with the radio buttons. In short, I want something like this:

- Radio Button

  - Check Box
- Radio Button

  - Select List
- Radio Button

where each radio button enables the control immediately below it.

The problem is that Jinja2 wants to render the radio buttons as a group with nothing between them; there doesn't seem to be a clean way to reference the individual button elements.

How do I render the individual radio buttons in the Jinja2 code? I'm using WTForms 2.3.3 and Flask 2.0.1.

For reference, here's the FlaskForm:

```
def list_sellers():
    c1 = aliased(Contact)
    c2 = aliased(Contact)
    return db.session.query(c2).
        select_from(c1).join(c2, c2.id==c1.seller_id).
        filter(c1.seller_id != None)
    
class ExportForm(FlaskForm):
    filtered = BooleanField('Apply Filters')
    sellers_filter = RadioField(
        'Filter by Seller',
        choices=[
            ('all', 'All Sellers'),
            ('select', 'Select Seller'),
            ('none', 'No Seller')
        ],
        validators=[Optional()]
    )
    seller = QuerySelectField(
        'Seller',
        query_factory=list_sellers,
        allow_blank=False,
        validators=[Optional()],
        render_kw={'class': 'form-select'},
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Download')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got something working, but IMHO it's really ugly:

```
{% for subfield in form.sellers_filter %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('0') %}
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('1') %}
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
      {{ form.seller }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if subfield.id.endswith('2') %}
    <div class="form.group col-4">
      {{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm gonna steal it anyway, in the absence of anything better.

Comment: @DavidWhite If somebody finds it useful, then, that's what we're here for!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line as well to have a code a bit shorter without extra "if" statement

```
{% for subfield in form.sellers_filter if subfield.id.endswith('0')%}
{{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of your question, it's somehow a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171711/how-to-render-a-field-when-radio-button-is-checked/69174404#69174404)

You need to write javascript code for your purpose.

Comment: I have the javascript working; it's getting Jinja2 to render one button element at a time instead of as a group that I'm having trouble with. I should have clarified that in my question, and have since done so.