# Find Selected Radio Button State

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to find out where the state of the radio buttons is saved within the browser, in order to find the selected one.

I did some research and I did find out that by using jQuery and the [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) on the `input` I can get the selected value.

Nevertheless, in the browser's HTML when clicking on a radio button nothing visually changes. Which makes me think, that this is impossible with Vanilla JS?

I am quite confused by the browser's behavior and in addition, I do not understand how the `serializeArray` is working.

The documentation states

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for successful controls to determine which elements it should include;

So I guess this is a black box and some magic happens in there, to determine the selected checkbox?

```js
function fun() {
  const a = $('#fieldset').find('input')
  const b = a.serializeArray()
    console.log(b)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey"
             checked>
      <label for="huey">Huey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
      <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
      <label for="louie">Louie</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="fun()">
click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using native JavaScript without jQuery, you can query for the selected radio button with the `:checked` selector.

```js
function fun() {
  const { value } = document.querySelector('input[name="drone"]:checked');
  console.log(value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4.33rem !important; }
```

```html
<fieldset id="fieldset">
  <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
    <label for="huey">Huey</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
    <label for="louie">Louie</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="fun()">Click Me</button>
```

As for the `serializeArray` question, it is doing something like this:

```js
const serializeArray = (formItem) => {
  const
    container = formItem.closest('form') ?? document.body,
    name = formItem.name;
  let value;
  switch (formItem.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'select':
    case 'textarea':
      value = formItem.value;
      break;
    case 'input':
      switch (formItem.type) {
        case 'text':
          value = formItem.value;
          break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
          value = container.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`).value;
          break;
      }
  }
  return [{ name, value }];
}

function fun() {
  const droneEl = document.querySelector('input[name="drone"]');
  const serialized = serializeArray(droneEl);
  console.log(serialized);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 6rem !important; }
```

```html
<fieldset id="fieldset">
  <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
    <label for="huey">Huey</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
    <label for="louie">Louie</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="fun()">Click Me</button>
```

The serialization usually occurs on the form, we can derive this information  for all form elements via:

```js
const formAsJson = (form) =>
  (formData =>
    [...formData.keys()].reduce((result, key) => ({
      ...result,
      [key]: result[key] ? formData.getAll(key) : formData.get(key)
    }), {}))
  (new FormData(form));

const serializeArray = (form) =>
  Object.entries(formAsJson(form))
    .flatMap(([name, value]) =>
      Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.map(item => ({ name, value: item }))
        : ({ name, value }));

const fun = () => {
  const serialized = serializeArray(document.forms.settings);

  console.log(serialized);
}
```

```html
<form name="settings">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
      <label for="huey">Huey</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="dewey">
      <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="louie">
      <label for="louie">Louie</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select options:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="time" value="morning" checked>
      <label for="huey">Morning</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="time" value="afternoon">
      <label for="dewey">Afternoon</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="time" value="evening">
      <label for="louie">Evening</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" onclick="fun()">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I feel less dump now :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the top voted answer from [How to get the selected radio button’s value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value), you could use the following Vanilla JavaScript to retrieve the currently selected value from the radio button:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="drone"]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this I think it will help you:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="drone"]:checked').value;
```